# Deserialize multiple XML elements in one object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlreader

I am using XmlSeriazlier to deserialize xml file.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
using (var reader = document.CreateReader())
   var result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Xml contains if/else if/else conditions which needs to be stored together in one object.

Sample Xml

```
<Layers>
  <If if="something" >
    <Layer name="something" />
  </If>
  <ElseIf if="anything" >
    <Layer name="anything" />
  </ElseIf>
  <Else>
    <Layer name="nothing" />
  </Else>

  <If if="something" >
    <Layer name="something" />
  </If>
  <ElseIf if="anything" >
    <Layer name="anything" />
  </ElseIf>

  <If if="something" >
    <Layer name="something" />
  </If>
  <Else>
    <Layer name="nothing" />
  </Else>
</Layers>
```

Syntax is same as programming language. I am wondering how I can store connected conditions together.

```
[XmlRoot("Layers")
public class Layers
{
    // TODO: Parse conditions to this list.
    public List<Condition> { get; set; }
}

public class Condition
{
    public If IfCondition { get; set; }
    public List<IfElse> IfElseConditions { get; set; }
    public Else ElseCondition { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some significant issues with that choice of xml schema that make it not really a good choice for `XmlSerializer`. Specifically, there is no notional `<Condition>` (or similar), which means that *from the serializer's perspective* there is nothing that groups those conditions. To *capture the data* you would need:

```cs
[XmlRoot("Layers")
public class Layers
{
    [XmlElement("If")]
    public List<If> { get; set; } // you may be able to share the inner type here
    [XmlElement("ElseIf")]
    public List<ElseIf> { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Else")]
    public List<Else> { get; set; }
}
```

but now you don't know which if elements go with which else-if elements, and go with which else elements.

I suspect you'd have to implement this manually, adding your own logic when changing between node type, but this isn't trivial. Frankly, it would probably be easier to reconsider the xml layout, if that is possible! For example:

```cs
<Layers>
  <Condition><!-- some kind of "first match wins" grouping -->
    <Match if="something">
        <Layer name="something" />
    </Match>
    <Match if="anything"><!-- note no need for different if/elseif -->
        <Layer name="anything" />
    </Match>
    <Match> <!-- no "if": acts as wildcard, i.e. "else" -->
        <Layer name="nothing" />
    </Match>
  </Condition>
  <!-- etc -->
</Layers>
```